# Could not execute automatic test using mstest.exe under Virtual Windows 8 Machine

Tags: windows, testing, automation, mstest, virtual-machine

I have the following issue: can not execute automatic test using mstest command under Virtual Windows 8 Machine. I enabled mstest logging and I came upon the following error:

> LocalControllerProxy: Exception Initializing ControllerObject or starting agent process(es): System.ArgumentException: The path is not of a legal form.
>      at System.IO.Path.NormalizePath(String path, Boolean fullCheck, Int32 maxPathLength)
>      at System.IO.Path.GetFullPathInternal(String path)
>      at System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(String path)
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.Common.ControllerDefaults.GetControllerWorkingDirectory()
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.Controller.ControllerObject..ctor(Boolean remote, ControllerConfiguration controllerConfiguration, AgentManager agentManager)
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.TestManagement.LocalControllerProxy.InitializeController(TestRun run)

The error in the trx file is:

> System.ArgumentException: The path is not of a legal form.
>      at System.IO.Path.NormalizePath(String path, Boolean fullCheck, Int32 maxPathLength)
>      at System.IO.Path.GetFullPathInternal(String path)
>      at System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(String path)
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.Common.ControllerDefaults.GetControllerWorkingDirectory()
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.Controller.ControllerObject..ctor(Boolean remote, ControllerConfiguration controllerConfiguration, AgentManager agentManager)
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.TestManagement.LocalControllerProxy.InitializeController(TestRun run)
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.TestManagement.ControllerProxy.QueueTestRunWorker(Object state)

The issues are gone and the test could be executed if I disable **Admin Approval Mode**, but in this case I could not run Metro apps. That's why I need to keep this option enabled.
Anyone experiencing such an issue? I've been trying to find a solution over the internet for the last 2 days, but with no avail.So I suppose this is not a common error.

Comment: If I use the built-in Administrator the tests could be executed.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for the issue.

I started the virtual machine, navigated to mstest.exe location -> right click -> Properties -> Compatibility tab -> Change settings for all users -> Run this program as an administrator.

It seems to me this is the most appropriate solution for now.